# redirecting console output to a file in unix

Tags: linux, unix, redirect, console, output

I have been trying to search for a file in my ftp server using find command

```
find ./* -iname "MyLog.log"
```

I am getting very large amount of output. I am trying to redirect this output into a file using the below commands.

```
find ./* -iname "MyLog.log"  > ./myfile/storeLog.log
```

and

```
find ./* -iname "MyLog.log"  tee ./myfile/storeLog.log
```

Still I am able to see the output in console but not in file.

Can anyone help me on how can i redirect the output to a file when we use find command in unix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possibly the large amount of output is "permission denied" type messages. Redirect errors to the log file by appending `2>&1`.

2 is the stream number for stderr (error messages), 1 is represents the stdout stream (the standard non-error output stream).

```
find . -iname "MyLog.log" > ./myfile/storeLog.log 2>&1
```